# How to save high res logos in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, export, eps

I have pretty basic Illustrator skills as I taught myself. I have revamped a clients logo in illustrator and they have asked for many colour variations but a high and low res version of each as EPS files (and I suppose jpeg files too). Whenever I save it as an EPS the logo is about 2MB and is pixelated if I zoom in even just a little. High res logos other clients have provided me are over 45MB. How do I get a high res EPS & JPEG?

Comment: You need to add some more information, because as it stands there isn't enough to tell what your problem is.  Does the EPS contain vectors, or did you rasterize the image?  EPS files can contain both vector and raster images.  How are you "zooming" in on the EPS? There's a chance you might just be zooming in on a preview, and not the actual EPS.  If the EPS contains vectors only, then it doesn't really have a resolution as such.  You can change the resolution of raster images when you export them.

Comment: Hi @BillyKerr That's almost an answer! If you'd make it one, I'd upvote it for sure. In all sincerety, please avoid answering questions in the comments. Comments are meant as temporary, asking for clarification only. Thanks!

Comment: @Vincent - OK, I've added it as an answer, or what might pass as almost an answer, kind of.

Answer (score 3):

45mb for a logo is huge!

For a high res jpeg you can simply go to file - export -then select jpeg from the drop down box and set the quality you require, higher the quality the larger the file size will be.

As for the EPS this is a vector format so is not dependent on resolution and can be scaled up and down without loss of quality. To export an EPS go to file - save as - choose EPS as the format.

I hope this helps.

Comment: An eps file may contain raster, vector, or both. So files can get pretty big depending on the contents.

Answer (score 2):

It might be worthwhile noting that EPS files can contain vector or raster images, or both. So without knowing what it contains, this question is not easy to answer. You should consider editing it to add details of what is contained in the EPS file.

If your EPS contains vectors only then it has no resolution as such.  Vectors have no pixels.

How are you "zooming" in on the EPS? There's a chance you might just be zooming in on a preview, and not the actual EPS. Previews are sometimes just low resolution raster images.

As for exporting raster images, you can change the resolution of raster images when you export them using the settings in the export dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing some of the terms here:

- EPS is a vector format and there is no 'low' and 'high res' when referring to vector artwork. Vector artwork can be used to generate raster artwork in any resolution you may need. In many cases prints can be produced from vector work without the need to use raster formats.
- JPG is a raster format and for this you can talk about 'low' and 'high res', both of which can be exported in Illustrator via different export settings
- a vector file (EPS in your case) can include non-vector (raster) artwork, in which case yeah you need to make sure you have plenty of resolution when using raster assets inside a vector file (which in turn can increase the file size of the vector file)